# How to retrieve list of WeChat Contacts in my app?

Tags: java, android, wechat

I am trying to access all of the WeChat contacts in my Android app and open Chat page with the contact on WeChat if the user taps on it. I read the official documentation from [Here](http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/mobile/getting-started/android#getting-started_android) but it didn't help. I couldn't find any helpful answers anywhere else either. In my code, I am filtering contacts by MIME Type but I am getting an empty string every time. Please help me solve it...

```
//MIMETYPE of WeCha
        String mimeString = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.tencent.mm.chatting.voip.video";

        String displayName = null;
        String phone = null;
        Long _id;
        ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        //Sorting contacts Alphabetically
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));

            phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //Getting the MimeType of user
            String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
If(mimeType==mimeString)
{

            //Logs for debugging
            Log.d("Look here", _id.toString());
            Log.d("Look here", displayName);
            Log.d("Look here", mimeType);
}
      }
        cursor.close();
```